# Rails delete record fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby app where I have a documents model. Documents can be added to a cart for download. Once the cart is downloaded the items in the cart can be wiped out and the cart deleted.  I am running into a problem when I try to destroy a document. I'm getting

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in DocumentsController#destroy
TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name 'tl.carts_documents'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM [tl].[carts_documents] WHERE [tl].[carts_documents].[document_id] = @0; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRows', N'@0 int', @0 = 3

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/technical_library

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:150:in `destroy'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"T0JBA. . . 3Q==",
 "id"=>"3"}
```

.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'category_id'
 # belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'Owner', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :carts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :carts
```

.

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

.
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160119182713) do

```
  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end


  create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "document_title"
    t.text     "summary"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
    t.string   "doc_file_file_name"
    t.string   "doc_file_content_type"
    t.integer  "doc_file_file_size"
    t.datetime "doc_file_updated_at"
    t.string   "owner_index"
    t.string   "category_index"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "document_id"
    t.string   "user"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "items", ["cart_id"], name: "index_items_on_cart_id"
```

.

```
def destroy




    @document.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to documents_url, notice: 'Document was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

This is running on a microsoft SQL server database but I don't think it is  a constraint issue.  My main question is if my models are correct to allow the deletion of a document. I don't care if that wipes out the associated items. Once the documents are downloaded, the cart and associated items are no longer used.

Comment: looks like it can't find the table. Are other queries working?

Comment: just `belongs_to :category` is enough - you don't have to tell ActiveRecord that `:class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'category_id'`. This is not java :)

Comment: Also you seem to be missing the `carts_documents` join table - its required for a habtm relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*has_and_belongs_to_many* relationship expects the join table be created as part of the migration. In your case, you are missing creation of 'carts_documents' in your migration.

Visit [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) and [Active Record API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) for more info

Comment: That worked. I created a model CartsDocuments with cart_id:integer and document_id:integer and it is now working.